# Update statement SQL with case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to update values for following condition

```
CREATE TABLE T 
  ( 
     C VARCHAR(10) 
  ); 

INSERT INTO T 
VALUES      ('0000'), 
            ('123456789'),
            ('A'), 
            (''),
            ('    '), 
            (NULL);
```

I need to leave the NULL values or values which has 0000 as is and update the remaining to 1234.

expected output as below:

```
0000
1234
1234
1234
1234
NULL
```

I have tried with below statement but is there a better way to do this?

```
UPDATE T SET C=CASE WHEN C IS NULL then null
when C='0000' then '0000' else '1234' END
```

Comment: To keep the transaction size down, don't update a column to the same value as before. Use WHERE to only update to new values.

Answer (score 2):

just use where clause ,you can try like below

```
update T
set C='1234'
where C<>'0000'
```

Comment: != is not an operator in t-sql

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis [It is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-exclamation?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Will update the '0000' as well. (Since '0000' is not null...)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `case` expression use `where` clause instead :

```
UPDATE t
     SET C = '1234'
WHERE C IS NOT NULL OR C <> '0000';
```

Comment: Will update the '0000' as well. (Since '0000' is not null...)

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
UPDATE T SET C='1234' where c <> '0000'
```

Will work since the null comparisons aren't *true*.

```
SQL>UPDATE T SET C='1234' where c <> '0000';

                  4 rows updated

SQL>select * from t;
C
==========
0000
1234
1234
1234
1234
-

                  6 rows found
```